# Differences in array push and spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I literally took 4 hours to debug this in React JS. I am sharing a simplified code to reproduce the same scenario. The following code is a state variable and its setter function; Have a look at it:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
setArr(prevArr => {
        prevArr.push(10);
        return prevArr;
})
```

The above code is supposed to add 10 into the state variable `arr`. But, it just adds `10` two times into the array. So, after the `setArr` worked, the new value of `arr` is `[10, 10]`.
I spent 4 hours to check if there were leaks in `useEffect` (that I am using in my code), or something else, until I found that the following code works as intended:

```js
setArr(prevArr => {
        return [...prevArr, number];
})
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour? Also, are there any similar cases that I might experience in future as a react developer?

Comment: `push` is modifying your array in place, so your state setter function returns the same state reference. When updating state, you're expected to return a new reference of what you're updating so React can detect the change (which is what you're doing by creating a new array and spreading the old one into the new onee), not the same reference (which is what you're doing in the first example)

Comment: See [updating arrays in state](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) (and also [updating objects in state](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state) where you'd have the same issue if you don't return a new object)

Comment: I understand that in the first example, I am returning the reference of the same array. But then I get the number added two times? What is the mechanism behind that? (I am a Data Structure guy, and would love going deep into it.)

Comment: @NickParsons.. Okay, the docuumentation got me satisfied!

Comment: State setter functions like the one you're using `prevArr => {` (and other functions like useEffect callbacks and the react component itself) execute twice if your component is wrapped in a React.StrictMode component, which is to help you catch side-effects and state mutations (like in your question). So that's why you're (most likely) getting `10` twice.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push()` method pushes the object passed in as a parameter into the same reference of the original array. Whereas, when using a spread operator it creates a new array with a copy of the old array.
Let's understand this example:

```
return [...prevArr, number];
```

Here, we're returning a value like this: `[]` which indicates JS to create a new array, then we're spreading the entries of previous array using the spread operator: `[...prevArr]` which indicates to copy all the entries of `prevArr` into this newly created array, and finally passing a new value: `[...prevArr, number]` will add a new element in the array apart from the other copied elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you use prevArr.push and return prevArr, it means the array object is still old one.

so react will bailout this state, meaning don't trigger rerender on this situation.